# Facebook App: What is the version upgrade and security review process for upgrading the Facebook app from v2.1 to v2.6

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a facebook app whose purpose is for grabbing user profile, page profile, posts, comments and etc. That app was of v2.1.

Now, we wanted to upgrade to v2.6. For this, we are creating the new app v2.6.
Additionally, in app2.6, we are adding the Webhook product for real time updates of user and page object.

The purpose of this new app is exactly same as that of v2.1.

What would be the best method for version upgrade and security review process? 
And how much time does Facebook take for these process.

Comment: You don’t need to create a new app. (And you shouldn’t, because that way you will lose all of your app’s active users; when they login again to your new app, you will get different app-scoped user ids for them.)

Comment: Ok. So, we need to upgrade existing v2.1 Facebook app to v2.6. Correct? And how do we do that? 

Since in the new app, we will work with "Webhook" so we will also add the Webhook.
In such case, should we submit the app for review? And how much time it might take for the review by Facebook (tentatively)?

Comment: What specifically requires review, and how long that usually takes, is in the documentation.

Comment: Ok. got it from the second question of the faq https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/faqs

Comment: In the faq, the first question, it does not mention if the upgrading app need to be submitted for review or not. So, does it mean, it does not require?

Comment: If you are asking for/using new stuff that requires review after your upgrade that you did not use before, then of course you need to get it reviewed now.

Comment: Regarding the upgrading to latest version, do you mean to use "API Upgrade Tool" for migrating old version 2.1 to latest version (2.6)?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115714/discussion-between-prakash-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade your existing App: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/api_versioning/

Alternatively, you can add the version to every API call. Upgrading the whole App with the Tool would be easier though.